# Jquery: parse RSS description content to text

Tags: jquery, rss

I ran into a problem today where the description text of an RSS feed resulted into an error while using a Jquery .text() method. I have the following string

```
"    De vertaalrechten voor het boek &lt;em&gt;Judas&lt;/em&gt; van Astrid Holleeder zijn verkocht aan de Amerikaanse uitgeverij Little, Brown.&amp;nbsp;"
```

and used the following jquery on the string:

```
rssDescriptionPlainText = $(data.rssEntries[i].description).text();
```

It works fine in most cases but today I got the follwoing error in the console:

```
"angular.js:13550 Error: [Error] Max Syntax error, unrecognized expression: De vertaalrechten voor het boek <em>Judas</em> van Astrid Holleeder zijn verkocht aan de Amerikaanse uitgeverij Little, Brown.&nbsp";
```

any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: what do you want to get from that content?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that, a plain text string with no html content inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do double unwrapping by using the `.html` and `.text`. That is, set the received content as a html content to a dummy element, and invoke text over it. You will get the pure html string without html entities. Now set the received html string as a html to another one dummy element, retrieve its text. That's it.

```
var content = "    De vertaalrechten voor het boek &lt;em&gt;Judas&lt;/em&gt; van Astrid Holleeder zijn verkocht aan de Amerikaanse uitgeverij Little, Brown.&amp;nbsp;"
var text = $('<span />').html($('<span />').html(content).text()).text();
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0uenoj3y/)